# Rails generating wrong attribute names from scaffolding

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm writing a rails app about videogame systems.
I used scaffolding to generate my model which contains the fields

```
:owns_ps_vita
:owns_nintendo_wii_u
```

But I get this:

```
 undefined method `owns_ps_vita'
```

On the /app/views/mymodel/_form.html.erb page.

I opened up the rails console and did

```
 MyModel.new
```

And saw in the results:

```
  owns_playstation_3: nil, owns: nil, ps_vita: nil,
  owns_nintendo_wii: nil, owns_nintendo_wii_
```

There's an extra "owns" there that should be attached to the ps_vita, and the u was dropped from the nintendo wii u.

I checked the app/models/MyModel.rb file and it looks correct.

```
  owns_nintendo_wii, :owns_nintendo_wii_u, :owns_playstation, :owns_playstation_2, :owns_playstation_3, :owns_ps_vita,
```

I scrolled up in terminal and verified my scaffolding didn't have a typo around that spot and it looks fine.

Comment: Can you post your schema.rb file? Check your migrations if the table doesn't look correct..

Comment: Migrations looks right:

      t.boolean :owns_nintendo_64
      t.boolean :owns_nintendo_wii
      t.boolean :owns_nintendo_wii_u

Comment: I don't see a schema.rb file. Inside db/ there is migrate/ and seeds.rb Inside migrate is the migration file the above comment is from.

Comment: Can you post your model?   Also the schema.rb will be helpful.

Comment: Also, I'd start from a brand new db if possible by running `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't yet have a `schema.rb` file, run `rake db:migrate` to create your database.

Comment: I did, I got an error that relation "My_Model" already exists.

Comment: Well, that's strange. Check your schema file to see if it exists and has content now, but try `rake db:reset` to reload your db.

Answer (score 0):

I see what you did.  When you created the migration, did you do something like this?

```
rails g migration add_stuff owns_nintendo_wii_u:string owns ps_vita:string
                                                           ^
                                                          (space)
```

It looks like your migration ran and created 2 columns:  `owns` and `ps_vita`.  You can verify this by looking at `schema.rb` or inspecting the database directly.

If you're using sqlite, then you can do this:

```
$ sqlite3 db/development.sqlite3

> .schema
  (spits out schema)
> .exit
```